# How to make EF understand that some columns are not nullable?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, null, nullable

I've defined this fine table.

```
create table WeirdDonkey (
  Tails int not null,
  Heads int default 7
)
```

When I run EF on it, it creates two fields as follows.

```
public int Tails { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> Heads { get; set; }
```

Now, I do understand why it thinks that the number of heads is nullable but it doesn't make any sense. A donkey can't have *null* heads. It can have 7 if nothing else is specified. (Well, that doesn't make any sense zoologically speaking but let's pretend we're on a different planet that follows the rules of my SQL magic).

How can I make EF understand that the default is 7 and there'll be no null-headed donkeys?

Comment: Giving a column a default value doesn't stop it from updating to a null value.

Comment: EF is right see [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415508). You can easily insert `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF is right.  `Heads` can have nulls.  What happens if after inserting a row, you decide to update a `Heads` value to `null`.  Will the database not accept it? Yes it will.

If you don't want nulls, you have to explicitly define it as such:

```sql
create table WeirdDonkey (
  Tails int not null,
  Heads int not null default 7
)
```

Comment: Oh, so stupid... I missed that, totally. Would you say it's wiser to go *not null* or add a *constraint*? The former seems easier, so I'd prefer that. But "easier" will often turn to be "less long-term"...

Comment: `not null` is a type of constraint anyways.  So yes, just use `not null`.  No point in using more verbose syntax.